# How to manipulate result from ajax request before jump to .then callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I am trying to add some variable on result from my ajax request before it goes to .then() callback. But my code always return result from ajax response to .then() statement.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "api.php",  //this returning [{"sid":"454545454554"}]
            success:function(data) {
                a = data.push({"additional_var" : "one"});
                return a;
            }
        })
        .then(function(response1){
            console.log(response1);           
        })
```

on the code above `response1` always return response from my api.php (`[{"sid":"454545454554"}]`). I expect the `response1` add `{"additional_var" : "one"}` before it goes to .then(). Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put everything inside the `.then`:

```
    .then(function(response1){
        response1.push({"additional_var" : "one"});
        console.log(response1);           
    })
```

Or chain another `.then` onto the beginning (not a good idea unless other parts of the code are consuming the Promise separately):

```
const prom = $.ajax({
  url: "api.php"
})
  .then(function(response1){
    response1.push({"additional_var" : "one"});
    console.log(response1);           
  })

prom.then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "api.php"
}).then(function(data) {
  data.push({
    "additional_var": "one"
  });
  return data;
}).then(function(response1) {
  console.log(response1);
})
```